# Wiringpi Python read multiple exit

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, wiringpi

hello i made this code but its not working well can you please help me

i need to read all the exit and execute an action
but when the code read the pin 65 for example he dont read the pin 82 and that not what i want

i got 2 mcp23017 connected to the raspberrypi
and need to read 32 exit

```
from cmath import pi
from turtle import delay
import wiringpi
from time import sleep  
  
pin_base = 65       # lowest available starting number is 65  
i2c_addr = 0x21     # A0, A1, A2 pins all wired to GND  
i2c_addr_2 = 0x23

#pins = [65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80]
#pins = [73,74,75,76,77,78,79,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73]
#      [____________________]     
#                 !
#             MCP1 ENTREE

wiringpi.wiringPiSetup()                    # initialise wiringpi  
wiringpi.mcp23017Setup(pin_base,i2c_addr)   # set up the pins and i2c address
wiringpi.mcp23017Setup(pin_base+16,i2c_addr_2)  
  
# Note: MCP23017 has no internal pull-down, so I used pull-up and inverted  
# the button reading logic with a "not"  

while True:
    for pin in range(65,72):
        wiringpi.delay(80)
        print(pin)
        wiringpi.pinMode(pin,1)
        pins=wiringpi.digitalRead(pin)
        if (pins==0):
            pin = pin + 8
            wiringpi.digitalWrite(pin,0)
            print('//1//')
            print(pin)
            pin = pin - 8
            wiringpi.delay(80)
        if (pins==1):
            pin = pin + 8
            wiringpi.digitalWrite(pin,1)
            print('//2//')
            print(pin)
            pin = pin - 8
            wiringpi.delay(80)
    for pin in range(81,88):
        wiringpi.delay(80)
        print(pin)
        wiringpi.pinMode(pin,1)
        pins=wiringpi.digitalRead(pin)
        if (pins==0):
            pin = pin + 8
            wiringpi.digitalWrite(pin,0)
            print('//1//')
            print(pin)
            pin = pin - 8
            wiringpi.delay(80)
        if (pins==1):
            pin = pin + 8
            wiringpi.digitalWrite(pin,1)
            print('//2//')
            print(pin)
            pin = pin - 8
            wiringpi.delay(80)
            
    print(pin)
    wiringpi.delay(80)
```